# How do I evaluate $\lim\limits_{z \to 1}\left(1-z\right)\tan{\dfrac{\pi z}{2}}$?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

The question is from *Differential and Integral Calculus* by Piskunov:

$$\lim\limits_{z \to 1}\left(1-z\right)\tan{\dfrac{\pi z}{2}}$$

I tried using the identity, $\tan{\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{1-\cos{x}}{\sin{x}}$ to simplify this to:

$$\lim\limits_{z \to 1}\left(1 - z\right)\dfrac{\sin{\pi z}}{1+\cos{\pi z}}$$

But I still can't solve this.

Comment: What is $z$? Is $z$ complex?

Comment: try taking $1-z=t\to 0$

Comment: In that form you have $0/0$ so you can use L'Hospital's rule. Alternatively you could say $\sin(\pi z/2) \sim 1$ and $\cos(\pi z/2) \sim -\pi/2 (z-1)$, both true to leading order as $z \to 1$, to reduce the problem without using the half angle identity.

Comment: Use the definition of the derivative with the cosine term.

Comment: @TobyMak No. $z$ is a real variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}\tan\left(\frac{\pi z}2\right)&=\tan\left(\frac{\pi(z-1)}2+\frac\pi2\right)\\&=-\cot\left(\frac\pi2(z-1)\right),\end{align}and that therefore\begin{align}\lim_{z\to1}(1-z)\tan\left(\frac{\pi z}2\right)&=\lim_{z\to1}\left(\frac{z-1}{\sin\left(\frac\pi2(z-1)\right)}\times\cos\left(\frac\pi2(z-1)\right)\right)\\&=\frac{\lim_{z\to1}\cos\left(\frac\pi2(z-1)\right)}{\lim_{z\to1}\frac{\sin\left(\frac\pi2(z-1)\right)}{z-1}}\text{ (since both limits exist)}\\&=\frac{\cos0}{\frac\pi2\cos0}\\&=\frac2\pi.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{z \to 1}\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi z}{2})}{1-z} = -\lim_{z \to 1}\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi z}{2}) -\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})}{z-1} = -\cos(\frac{\pi x}{2})' \left|\frac{}{}_{x=1} \right. =\frac{\pi}{2}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
and $$\lim_{z \to 1}\sin(\frac{\pi z}{2}) = 1 $$
Combining the above two
$$\lim_{z \to 1}(1-z)\tan(\frac{\pi z}{2}) = \lim_{z\to 1}\frac{1-z}{\cos(\frac{\pi z}{2})} \cdot \lim_{z \to 1}\sin(\frac{\pi z}{2}) = \frac{2}{\pi}\cdot 1$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $t:=\dfrac\pi2(1-z)$.

$$\lim\limits_{z \to 1}\left(1-z\right)\tan{\dfrac{\pi z}{2}}=\frac2\pi\lim\limits_{t \to 0}t\cot t=\frac2\pi\lim\limits_{t \to 0}\frac t{\sin t}\cdot\lim\limits_{t \to 0}\cos t.$$